# pandas df - sort on index but exclude first column from sort

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I want to sort this df on rows ('bad job') but I want to exclude the first column from the sort so it remains where it is:

```
          Radisson   Marriott   Hilton      IHG     
Category                                        
good job  0.214941   0.40394    0.448931    0.375316
bad  job  0.514941   0.10394    0.348931    0.475316
crap job  0.114941   0.20394    0.548931    0.175316
```

expected output:

```
          Radisson   IHG        Hilton     Marriott   
Category                                        
good job  0.214941   0.375316   0.448931   0.40394
bad  job  0.514941   0.475316   0.348931   0.10394 
crap job  0.114941   0.175316   0.548931   0.20394
```

I don't know to edit my code below to exclude the 1st column from the sort:

```
 df = df.sort_values(by=[df.index[1]], axis=1, ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.argsort.html) with add `1` for possible add first value `0` by [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) for positions, last change columns order by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
s = df.iloc[0]
df = df.iloc[:, ((-s[1:]).argsort() + 1).reindex(df.columns, fill_value=0)]
print (df)
          Radisson    Hilton  Marriott       IHG
Category                                                     
good job  0.214941  0.448931   0.40394  0.375316
```

Comment: jezrael, if there are more than 1 row can I pass in the row I was to use? Like this: 'df = df.iloc[5:, ((-s[1:]).argsort() + 1).reindex(df.columns, fill_value=0)]'

Comment: @Boosted_d16 - hmmm, there is problem, because 2d data. So there are problem if sorting in one row, in another row is different order. Can you add sample data with expected output for this?

Comment: @Boosted_d16 - So it is sorting by first row, if sorting by second one,or third, there is different order, what do you think?

Comment: correct. The order will change depending on the row being selected but excluding the first column.

Comment: @Boosted_d16 - Ok, so is impossible pass more columns, right? Still not sure if understand well.

Comment: apologies, I'm probably not doing a good job at explaining it. Only the 1st column will be fixed. The rest of the columns will be sorted on a given row.

Comment: @Boosted_d16 - yes, it do my solution, for you not working? `s = df.iloc[0]` menas sort by first row of data

Answer (score 0):

try

```
df1 = pd.concat([df[[df.columns[0]]],df.reindex(sorted(df.columns[1:]), axis=1)],axis=1)
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading. From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_